# Loading an R Package from a Custom directory

Tags: r, installation, package

If I download an "package-name".tar.gz file from CRAN website, gunzip and untar it into a custom directory, how do I load that package from within R?  I cannot extract the file in the R installation directory.

Comment: Please add a bit more info on operating system and why exactly you want to install a package from source. If you're not familiar with R, please read the recommended manuals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a package without installing it in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484903/how-do-i-load-a-package-without-installing-it-in-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add some extra information on the operating system. If you're on windows, you need Rtools ( http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/ ) to build from source. See that website for more information on how to install everything you need.

Even when you're on Linux, simply extracting the package-file doesn't work. There might be underlying C-code (which is the case for the `MSBVAR` package), and even R code has to be processed in order to be built into a package that can be loaded directly with the `library()` function.

Plus, you have to take into account that the package you want to install might have dependencies. For the `MSBVAR` package, these are the packages `coda` and `bit`. When building from source, you need to make sure all dependencies are installed as well, or you can get errors.

apart from the R CMD INSTALL you could try from within R :

```
# from CRAN
install.packages("MSBVAR", type="source")
# from a local file 
install.packages("/my/dir/MSBVAR.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")
```

or why not just do

```
# from CRAN
install.packages("MSBVAR")
```

This works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 55):

Try using Hadley Wickham's [`devtools` package](https://github.com/hadley/devtools), which allows loading packages from a given directory:

```
library(devtools)

# load package w/o installing
load_all('/some/package/diR')

# or invoke 'R CMD INSTALL'
install('/some/package/diR')
```

Comment: `ERROR: cannot install to srcdir for package ‘RPostgreSQL’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL’
Error: Command failed (1)` :-(

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the package to a directory to which you have permission to read and write. First, download the package to an easily accessible directory. If you're on Linux/Mac, try creating a directory called 'rlib' in your home directory.

```
cd ~; mkdir rlib
R CMD INSTALL MSBVAR.tar.gz --library=rlib
```

If you would prefer to install the package from R, do this:

```
## From CRAN
install.packages("MSBVAR", lib="~/rlib")
```

Answer (score 3):

I run into a similar problem and to load an R Package from a custom directory you can also use the `lib.loc` option of the `library()` function.

In my case, I had to install the package to a custom directory due to admin restrictions. Below, I tried to install it in the default library directory, but I was forced to change that to another directory:

```r
install.packages('data.table')
Warning in install.packages("data.table") :
  'lib = "/software/all/R/4.1.2-foss-2021b/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) yes
Would you like to create a personal library
‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
to install packages into? (yes/No/cancel) yes
```

So I ended up with installing the package in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1` This will depend from case to case, so pay attention to the messages given by `install.packages('data.table')` so that you get the right path.

Then to load that package, I had to do just this:

```r
library(data.table, lib.loc = '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1')
```

This option does not require any other dependencies.

Comment: Strange that this is the only answer with `lib.loc`, i.e. answer to the actual question (which is about a custom *import* location, not custom *install* location where the accepted answer digressed...)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `R CMD INSTALL downloadedpackage.gz`?

As I understand it, this should install the package in your user-space if it cannot get write permissions to the R installation folder

Comment: I tried that, but I got an "ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MSBVAR'".

Comment: Maybe if you paste the error into your question you would get more useful answers?  I'm guessing it has some C compilation that needs doing.  You're either going to need to download a binary package for your specific platform, or get a compiler set up correctly.

Comment: Does the binary package from here not work? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSBVAR/index.html

Comment: If compilation failed then there should be an earlier error saying why. Maybe you don't have a C or Fortran compiler installed. What OS are you using?

Comment: my OS is: sparc-sun-solaris2.10.  Before the error message I also get an "sh: make: not found" message.  I tried loading all of the dependencies, and then using install.packages on the tar.gz file.  I guess at this point, I will just have to wait for IT to install it...

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to unzip or untar 
just give this command in command prompt and it will unzip into appropriate place

`R CMD INSTALL [options] [l-lib] pkgs.tar.gz`

as explained [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/packages.html)

then you can use it in R by `library(the_pkg)`