# How do I load a package without installing it in R?

Tags: r

I have built an R package but I do not want my users to have to install it before using it.

Is there a way to load a package without having to install it?

For example, if I have a package `mypackage.tar.gz`, is there something like

```
library("mypackage.tar.gz")
```

?

Comment: Why would you not want people to have to install your package? And, no, I don't think it is possible to do what you want - you need to have the files installed somewhere for `library()` to work and that is, AFAIK, the only way to really use a package in R. You can source all the R code from anywhere into the current session, even into an environment so it looks *like* a package, but there is no help, no loading of dependencies etc.

Comment: -1 for cross posting to r-help

Comment: @Grothendieck you're downvoting me for trying to find an answer on another site???

Comment: Duplicate of [Loading a package without having to install it?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/273462.html)

Comment: more for not mentioning it, I guess...

Comment: Questions asked on a different forum are not even mentioned in the StackOverflow guidelines; not to mention that this question did not get an answer on the other forum. Are you sure it is to be considered a duplicate? I am not. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll join in "the chorus" of suggesting you should really install the package.

That having been said, you can take a look at Hadley's [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) package, which will let you load packages into the workspace without dumping in your global workspace.

The package will have to be untar'd/unzipped and follow the standard R package structure.

In order for this to work, though, your users would have to have the devtools package installed, so ... I'm not sure that this is any type of win for you.

Comment: To be more explicit the command would be `devtools::load_all("path/to/mypkg")`.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the code to be loaded without it being installed, take the raw R script and source it:

```
source(myScript.R)
```

If you have different functions, you can create an R script that just loads all the necessary source files. What I sometimes do when developing, is name all my functions F_some_function.R and my classes Class_some_function.R. This allows me to source a main file containing following code :

```
funcdir <- "C:/Some/Path"
files <- dir(funcdir)
srcfiles <- c(grep("^Class_",dir(funcdir),value=T),
              grep("^F_",dir(funcdir),value=T)
)

for( i in paste(funcdir,srcfiles,sep="/")) source(i)
```

If you present them with the tarred file, they can untar themselves using `untar()` before sourcing the main file.

But honestly, please use a package. You load everything in the global environment (or in a specified environment if you use local=T), but you lose all functionality of a package. Installing a package is no hassle, and removing neither.

If it's a matter of writing rights on the C drive (which is the only possible reason not to use a package that I met in my carreer), one can easily set another library location. R 2.12 actually does this by itself on Windows. See `?.libPaths()`

Comment: Here, here.  Packages were invented for a reason!